# Java Spring Boot Many to Many

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have 2 entities, connected by many to many. The template should list:

Owner1
shelter1
shelter 2
Owner1
shelter 1

How can I connect the Owner and the Shelter in the controller so that I can pinch into the template

**Owner 1- his shelters**

**Owner 2 - His Shelters**

The whole problem is in the controller, what exactly should I pass to the template engine? This is the whole problem, thanks in advance for the answers and time taken

```java
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "owner")
    public class Owner {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int idOwner;

        private String name;

        private String address;

        private String description;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "owner_shelter",  
                   inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "shelter_id") })
        private List<Shelter> shelters = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addShelter(Shelter shelter) {
           shelters.add(shelter);
           shelter.getOwners().add(this);
        }

        public void removeShelter(Shelter shelter) {
          shelters.remove(shelter);
          shelter.getOwners().remove(this);
        }   
     }
```

```java
        @Data
        @DynamicUpdate
        @AllArgsConstructor
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Builder
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "shelter")
        public class Shelter {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private int id;

            private String name;

            private String address;

            private String description;

            @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shelters")
            private List<Owner> owners;

            public void addOwner(Owner owner) {
                owners.add(owner);
                owner.getShelters().add(this);
            }

            public void removeOwner(Owner owner) {
                owners.remove(owner);
                owner.getShelters().remove(this);
            }

        }
```

now i can print only list of shelter or owner

```java
        @Autowired
        ShelterRepository shelterRepository;

        @Autowired
        OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

        @GetMapping("/shelters")
        public String getPage(Authentication authentication, Model model) {
            if (authentication != null) {
                model.addAttribute("authentication", authentication);
            }
            List<Shelter> shelters = shelterRepository.findAll();
            List<Owner> owners = ownerRepository.findAll();
            model.addAttribute("shelters", shelters);
            model.addAttribute("owners", owners);
            return "shelterList";
        }
```